# XSLT create list from paragraphs

Tags: html, xslt

I have encountered a section of HTML from a well-known Sci-Fi publisher that attempts to mimic an ordered list using paragraphs as anonymous tags. A sample is as follows:

```
<p class="NL1">1. first list item.</p>
<p class="NL">2. second list item.</p>
<p class="NL">3. third list item.</p>
<p class="NLL">4. last list item.</p>
```

I want to use XSLT to convert this abomination to a real ordered list. What I have tried is:

```
    <xsl:template name="makeLi">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='NL1' 
        and preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::p[@class='NL1'])]]" >
        <ol>
            <xsl:call-template name="makeLi"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[(self::p[@class='NL'])
                or (self::p[@class='NLL'])]"/>
        </ol>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='NL'
        and preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::p[@class='NL'])]
        and preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::p[@class='NL1'])]]" >
        <xsl:call-template name="makeLi"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='NLL' and preceding-sibling::node()[not(self:::p)]]" >
            <xsl:call-template name="makeLi"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

When I apply this transformation, what I end up with is:

```
<ol>
  <li>1. first list item.</li>
  <li>2. second list item.</li>
  <li>3. third list item.</li>
  <li>4. fourth list item.</li>
</ol>
<ul>
  <li>2. second list item.</li>
  <li>3. third list item.</li>
  <li>4. fourth list item.</li>
</ul>
```

How can I prevent the "NL" and "NLL" classes from being processed a second time?

Comment: Which XSLT version?

Comment: So what is the exact semantics of those `class` attribute values? What does `NL1`, `NL` and `NLL` stand for?

Comment: If you are using XSLT 2 or 3, look at grouping with `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` or `group-adjacent`: [tag:xslt-grouping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0, sibling recursion is the way to go, and you're on the right lines. Not tested, but something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@class='NL1']" mode="normal">
  <ol>
    <xsl:call-template name="makeLi"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1]" mode="list"/>
  </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='NL']" mode="list">
  <xsl:call-template name="makeLi"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1]" mode="list"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='NLL']" mode="list">
  <xsl:call-template name="makeLi"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='NL' or @class='NLL']" mode="normal"/>
```

I added `mode="normal"` for the default processing mode just for emphasis, you should leave it out if using the default (unnamed) mode.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was mostly the solution. I removed 'mode="normal"' as I was using the default node, but left in the 'mode="list"'. The key part here was the template match for the non-list mode, which causes the "list item paragraphs" to be ignored when not included in the ```<ol>``` block.